# Help understand 「せきこみ、喉から込み上げる命の源を思うさまに吐き出す」

Tags: grammar, words

I'm stuck in this paragraph :

> 叫び声を上げようと口を開いた瞬間、こぼれ出たのは絶叫ではなく血塊だ。
> 　せき込み、喉からこみ上げる命の源を思うさまに吐き出す。ごぼごぼと、口の端を血泡が浮かぶほどの吐血。

I don't fully understand the following sentence :

> せきこみ、喉から込み上げる命の源を思うさまに吐き出す。

What I understand is :

> He cough violently, and threw out at the fact he was thinking at the 命の源 which was making him wanting to throw up.

It might seem like gibberish but I don't want to translate, I just want to understand

What does 喉からこみ上げる really means ? I understand it as something that makes up have 吐き気, is it right ?

How to read the 源 ? みなもと　？　げん？

What is the meaning of さまに exactly ? I saw on the dictionary that it means a "state", but how is it different to "思うことに吐き出す" or something like that ?

Is 吐き出す "vomit" or "say frankly" in this sentence ? I understand it as vomit, but a japanese friend told me that it mainly meant "思いをぶちまける"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ [ ( 喉からこみ上げる→)命の源 ] を } ( 思うさまに ) 吐き出す。
```

- 喉からこみ上げる命の源 is a noun phrase that functions as the direct object of 吐き出す.

  - 喉からこみ上げる (lit. "welling up from the throat") is a relative clause that modifies 命の源.
  - 命の源 (lit. "the source of life") in this context metaphorically refers to his blood. This 源 is read みなもと.
- 思うさまに is an idiomatic adverbial phrase which usually means the same as 思うままに/思う存分 ("at one's disposal", "in abandon", "as much as one wishes"). See [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/33367/meaning/m0u/). In this context, it's closer to 思い切り ("with all one's might"). It modifies 吐き出す.
- 吐き出す means (physically) "to throw up".

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but let me try:

- 喉から: from throat
- こみ上げる : building up
- [命]{いにち}の[源]{みなもと}：source of life/ life energy
- を思う[さま]{よう}に：thinking like
- 吐き出す: vomit out/ throw up

so, the meaning could be:

> Coughing like throwing up his source of life (that is building up) out of his throat.

I think さま：様：よう means similar. And the 吐き出す is definitely vomit, because the context is that he is sick, coughing and throwing up some blood...

Comment: 思うさま - 【おもうさま】 (adv) to one's heart's content